# unrecognised error while sending arguments from python to java

Tags: java, python

I am trying to pass argument from my java GUI to the python algorithm. I have tried many ways but I keep getting unrecognized argument as the error. I am using Process builder to integrate the python code to my java. i need to send fav_movie from java to python.

this is a part of the python code. i am a python beginner so it would be helpful if you could please tell me what is causing this error

```
  def _fuzzy_matching(self, hashmap, fav_movie):
        """
        return the closest match via fuzzy ratio.
        If no match found, return None
        Parameters
        ----------
        hashmap: dict, map movie title name to index of the movie in data
        fav_movie: str, name of user input movie
        Return
        ------
        index of the closest match
        """
        match_tuple = []
        # get match
        for title, idx in hashmap.items():
            ratio = fuzz.ratio(title.lower(), fav_movie.lower())
            if ratio >= 60:
                match_tuple.append((title, idx, ratio))
        # sort
        match_tuple = sorted(match_tuple, key=lambda x: x[2])[::-1]
        if not match_tuple:
            print('Oops! No match is found')
        else:
            print('Found possible matches in our database: '
                  '{0}\n'.format([x[0] for x in match_tuple]))
            return match_tuple[0][1]
def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        prog="Movie Recommender",
        description="Run KNN Movie Recommender")
    parser.add_argument('--path', nargs='?', default='C:\java programs\qcri 3\ml-latest-small',
                        help='input data path')
    parser.add_argument('--movies_filename', nargs='?', default='movies.csv',
                        help='provide movies filename')
    parser.add_argument('--ratings_filename', nargs='?', default='ratings.csv',
                        help='provide ratings filename')
    parser.add_argument('--movie_name', nargs='?', default='',
                        help='provide your favourite movie name')
    parser.add_argument('--top_n', type=int, default=10,
                        help='top n movie recommendations')
    return parser.parse_args()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # get args
    args = parse_args()
    data_path = args.path
    movies_filename = args.movies_filename
    ratings_filename = args.ratings_filename
    movie_name = args.movie_name
    top_n = args.top_n
    # initial recommender system
    recommender = KnnRecommender(
        os.path.join(data_path, movies_filename),
        os.path.join(data_path, ratings_filename))
    # set params
    recommender.set_filter_params(50, 50)
    recommender.set_model_params(20, 'brute', 'cosine', -1)
    # make recommendations
    recommender.make_recommendations(movie_name, top_n)
```

this is the error shown:

```
usage: Movie Recommender [-h] [--path [PATH]]
                         [--movies_filename [MOVIES_FILENAME]]
                         [--ratings_filename [RATINGS_FILENAME]]
                         [--movie_name [MOVIE_NAME]] [--top_n TOP_N]
Movie Recommender: error: unrecognized arguments: toy
```

this is the java code that accesses the python:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ScriptException, InterruptedException
    {


        System.out.println("enter movie name");
        Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
        String name= s.nextLine();

         ProcessBuilder pb= new ProcessBuilder("python","recomold.py",name);
         System.out.println("running file");
         Process process = null;
        try {
            process = pb.start();
            inheritIO(process.getInputStream(), System.out);
            inheritIO(process.getErrorStream(), System.err);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         int err= process.waitFor();
         System.out.println("any errors?"+(err==0 ? "no" : "yes ")+err);
         try {
            System.out.println("python output "+ output(process.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

   }

    private static void inheritIO(InputStream src, PrintStream dest) {
         new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Scanner sc = new Scanner(src);
                    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                        dest.println(sc.nextLine());
                    }
                }
            }).start();
    }

    private static String output(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader br = null;
            try{
                br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line = null;
                while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                br.close();
            }
            return sb.toString();
    } 
}
```

Comment: You should post your java code and how you invoke python script from java app.

Comment: @GhostCat I have added the java code. I am using Process builder to access the python code. And when i type just toy and run the python code in module it works. so i dont think that is the error?

Comment: Looks like your python script expects a `--movie_name` before the movie name.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch could you expand on that please?

Comment: Err. The python script clearly tells you how to invoke it. You can see there that it only accepts some - -option value input. You are passing that "name" argument without any - -whatever in front of it. Hint: start by invoking the script manually on the command line. Understand how to properly use it before calling it from Java!

Comment: Seriously: read the usage information for that script. It clearly tells you how it should be called! Then look at the way you are calling it!

Comment: How we can say this more clearly.  You have defined your python program to be called like this:  `python recomold.py --move_name toy`.  (That is what the usage message say, and that is how I read the code for the python argument parser you have written.)  You are actually calling the python script like this: `python recomold.py toy`

Comment: And note: this has nothing to do with python specifically. The only thing that matters is the usage information for the tool you are calling. It only required you to read the message and then cross check your way of invoking the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your Python script does not accept a non-option argument as proper input.  According to the help text for your Python program, any arguments you provide must come in option/value pair form, like this:

```
--<option_name> <option_value>
```

But you're just passing "toy" with no option specifier.  So maybe what you want is something like this in your Java code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb= new ProcessBuilder("python","recomold.py","--movie-name",name);
```